# Grid-like view for items tagged by user?

Tags: 2010, social

This is somewhat related to [my previous question on social tagging](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37084/view-list-of-items-tagged-i-like-it).

I'd like to know if there's any web parts, either out-of-the-box or third party, which provide a more traditional grid view structure that would allow users to view the pages they've tagged, remove tags, etc.