# WebPart displaying 'i like it' marked elements of website

Tags: search, social-tag

I want to put a WebPart on a WebPart page, that displays all elements (files, list items, pages) of the same Website or Site Collection that the user has marked with 'i like it'.

Is there a existing WebPart to do this? Or is there a way to find these elements with the search? With a KQL query like `"path:http://sharepoint/ tage:ilikeit"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37084/view-list-of-items-tagged-i-like-it

Comment: not a duplicate: the question linked asks for a place to find the tagged items, this will not help me, I'm looking for a way to put this information on a page in the portal ...

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the tag profile page it will list out all of the items that were tagged with "I Like it" by all users throughout the site.

On that page there is a link to a search results page.  It should say something like "To find content related to 'I like it' in search, please click here."

That link will lead to a search result page and show a query similar to this:  **SocialTagId:"d66c242d-7bdb-400c-9701-5158041b84f1"**

The guid represents the I like it value in your term store.

To filter it by the current user you would need to add a user filter to the query something like **AND author:"[current_user]"**

To filter it for the current site you would need to add a site filter to the query something like **AND site:"[site url]"**

Comment: Ok, when I just search for the SocialTagId, there are more contents showing up, then I tagged with "I Like it" ... so I added AND author:"xxx" as you suggested, but then there are no results... Is this filter right? Because I'm not really the author of these documents, I just "liked" them ...

Comment: @Hinek I may incorrectly assumed that it would associate the author of the tag, but since you are searching for items, it would likely see that as the author of the document.